# How to access JDT "static" icon from an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I found out how to access some icons:

```
ISharedImages images = JavaUI.getSharedImages();
Image image = images.getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_WHATEVER);
```

However, in `ISharedImages` are constants modifier icons like `IMG_FIELD_PUBLIC` and `IMG_OBJS_PRIVATE` etc., but I cannot find any for e.g. the `static` modifier.

I believe all of the icons in this list should somehow be accessible, but how?
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-156.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatelly the only way I know if you use internal call. Add `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` as a dependency to your project. Then you will be able to use the JDT internal mechanism:

```
JavaPluginImages.get(JavaPluginImages.IMG_OBJS_CLASS); // returns an Image
```

I think with that you can use whichever icon you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. For the static icon (`JavaPluginImages.DESC_OVR_STATIC`), an `ImageDescriptor` is returned.
Anyway, this method is "discouraged" by eclipse, but I see no other way to do it...