# Retrieving a java element's javadoc url in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, url, javadoc, eclipse-jdt

Is there an API method in Eclipse to retrieve the URL for the Javadoc of an element?

I noticed that org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI appears to have a static function that accomplishes just that. You feed it an element and it returns the URL if it exists.

The problem I have is that I'm wanting to use this in connection with a plugin I'm using in Eclipse. You generally can't access the JDT classes unless you go somewhat roundabout it and this is discouraged by the Eclipse developers. So my question is is there another (easy) way to get the Javadoc URL for an element that doesn't require me to go too far out of my way?

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI is public API.  Can you be more specific about what you actually can't access?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what other questions have said. (Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379789/how-to-access-jdt-static-icon-from-an-eclipse-plugin). I have gotten access by adding the JDT.ui as a dependency to the project, but without doing that, its not directly accessible. And I've heard that adding it as a dependency, is what is discouraged.

Comment: It is not discouraged to add jdt.ui as a dependency.  The only thing that is discouraged is to access internal classes (ie- any class that have a package fragment named 'internal').  Even though it is discouraged, you still can do it if you really, really need to.

Comment: It would be surprising if there is, because URL can be changed based on version.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the source code, you can get the class hierarchy. Then can access by using the same URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ plus the class path. For example, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for ArrayList class.